# In what sense are photons emergent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, elementary-particles, gauge-symmetry

Recently I read in an [essay by Wilczek](http://frankwilczek.com/2013/listOfTen.pdf):

"Photons are mixtures of weak B3 and hypercharge C mesons. It is those objects, not the emergent photon, whose properties are ideally simple."

Until now I thought that photons are **elementary** massless spin-1 bosons that arise as gauge bosons for the $U(1)$ symmetry in (quantized) electrodynamics. They can be described by a four-vector $A_\mu$ including two unphysical degrees of freedom that can be eliminated by introducing the gauge-invariant four-rotation $F_{\mu\nu} := \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu$ so that only the two polarisations (helicity $h = \pm 1$) remain.

Where does the emergence of the photon come from? Is this related to electroweak symmetry breaking and the Higgs field? Why are mesons (hadrons) mentioned??

Comment: See the [Wikipedia article on EW symmetry breaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_interaction#Formulation). Above the EW transition neither the photon nor the Z exist. They appear at low energies due to mixing of two of bosons that exist before the EW symmetry is broken. I guess Wilczek's point is that the higher symmetry before the EW transition makes the physics simpler.

Comment: Photons are not a mixture of *mesons* (which would be quark-antiquark pairs). They simply are a mixture of two other electroweak gauge bosons such that their combination remains massless after the Higgs SSB. (Mass eigenstates are the "naive" physical states) I've never heard the word *emergence* being used to describe that, and I do not understand the question.

Comment: Exactly, this sentence with "mixtures of mesons" is what I dont understand in the essay by Wilczek. I understand the spontaneous breaking of EW symmetry, but I only knew mesons as hadrons until now!

Comment: It seems obvious from the context that Wilczek means gauge bosons not mesons.

Comment: I vaguely remember reading of an 'archaic' use of "meson" to mean intermediate vector boson.  For an example from 1967, [see this](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1968AuJPh..21..139C) which refers to a *"... the W meson or intermediate boson..."*

Comment: From 1964: [Mass and Interactions of the W Meson](http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.134.B1295) *"Some possible sources of a large mass for the weak vector meson, or W meson, are studied."*  So, from the context, "meson" here is not used to mean a quark-antiquark bound state.

Comment: You're asking some great questions. It would really help if you filled in your profile (if you don't mind the privacy issues) so that people can help gauge your level.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the advice. I am a Physics graduate student and just joined yesterday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this related to electroweak symmetry breaking and the Higgs field?

Yes.  There is a particular mixture of the $W^0$ and $B$ bosons that propagates freely in the Higgs field condensate; this freely propagating state is the photon.

> Why are mesons (hadrons) mentioned??

There was a time when the weak intermediate vector bosons were referred to as "W mesons".  For example, see this APS paper from 1964, [Mass and Interactions of the W Meson](http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.134.B1295)